# IRremote library and Moteino

Tags: wifi, ir

Does somebody know if the [IRremote library](http://www.righto.com/2009/08/multi-protocol-infrared-remote-library.html) is compatible with Moteino boards?

If not, do you know a cheap solution to build a IR-remote controllable via wireless?

Comment: Yes, the moteino is just an UNO clone using the same ATMega328P microcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

You need two spare digital pins to use the IR-library. These pins can be set to whatever you like. Pins D3 to D7 are free on the Moteino so the library will be OK to use if you connect the IR LED and receiver to two of those pins.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Arduino do not need to be wireless to be able to control it wirelessly. 
If you have a wireless network at home (which most people do), there is usally some ethernet RJ45 ports as well. 
So instead you use a very cheap ENC28J60 to connect your arduino to the network. You can then access your Arduino wirelessly through your home router. As long as it is connected to your local network its should work.

As for connecting the IR sender and reciever, you need as said before, one digital pin for recieving IR-signals and one digital pin for sending. Which should be no problem even when adding the ENC28J60. It should also work very well with the Moteino if you choose to go that way.